# How does Jorah Mormont know who Thoros of Myr is?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the S07E05 Eastwatch of Game of Thrones

> Ser Jorah Mormont walked down the dungeon at EastWatch castle where Thoros, Beric & Hound are held in a prison.
>  **Jorah**: "Thoros? I hardly recognized you."
>  **Thoros**: "Ser Jorah Mormont. They wont give me anything to drink down here."

How does Jorah know Thoros. AFAIK they havn't met. Have they?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From [/r/freefolk](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/6tjifo/main_spoilers_just_a_reminder_of_how_jorah_and/?st=j6d9cg4y&sh=9f395aca), the trusted subreddit for GoT spoilers and news:

> During Balon Greyjoy's first rebellion, (nine years before the start
>   of the story) the amassed army of King Robert Baratheon laid siege on
>   Pyke. When the first wall fell, it was Jorah who charged first into
>   the Ironborn stronghold, followed by Thoros of Myr, who charged with a
>   flaming sword. Just to clarify, this act of courage is why Jorah was
>   knighted even though he is a northerner. That's how they know each
>   other.

Jorah recalls the event mentioned above in this video:

> JORAH: It was a bitch of a siege
>
> BARRISTAN: Mm. You were first through the breach at Pyke
>
> JORAH: The second. Thoros of Myr went in alone, waving that flaming sword off his
>
> BARRISTAN: [laughing] Thoros of Myr! Bloody madman. Robert knighted you after the battle

Comment: Good answer, I've added the relevant transcript. Only other thing I can think to add is Thoros is occasionally mentioned as being well-known on the tournament circuit (crowd favourite due to his flaming sword), as was Jorah (whose impressive antics won him his first failed marriage), and how Thoros admitted that in his cynical youth he essentially interpreted "convert Westeros to the Lord Of Light" as "impress Westeros knights with your drinking and fighting then see what happens". Jorah's comment in this scene suggests they were tourney drinking buddies as well as fighting together at Pyle

Comment: So the first quote one says Jorah was first, and Thoros was second. The second says Thoros was first and Jorah was second. Which one is it?

Comment: The fact that Barristan repeats the first quote in the second quote suggests that this is what everyone *thinks* happened -- this is the story in the official history perhaps, while Jorah -- who was right there doing it -- knows the truth of whether he was first or second and presumably has no reason to make himself seem slightly less impressive in that conversation with Ser Barristan, so is presumably telling the truth, perhaps out of a sense of honour. Further, the first quote is unsourced while the second has a quote from the show (being posted here, it's the show-canon being asked about).

Comment: Further, one of the edits to that post that was linked for the first quote says it was actually Thoros first in the books as well, so show and books agree, and the quote is incorrect factually, though it agrees with Ser Barristan's understanding of what happened.